# Get my recent checkins on a venue

Tags: foursquare

I looked everywhere on the foursquare api,
but it doesn't seem to be possible to get a user (the one that is authenticated) his latest checkins.
And I mean the full object or some id's, not only the amount.

Is there any way of obtaining this information?

The alternative is requesting a lot of history checkins and filter them, but this is not optimal.

The goal:
I want to know the place where the user checked in (the coordinates of the checkin, not the checked in venue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A check-in happens at a venue, and there's no differentiation between the lat/lon of a check-in versus the lat/lon of the venue that the check-in was at. You can see a history of a user's check-ins with the [users/checkins](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/users/checkins) endpoint.